# Nested flexbox groups

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like 2 groups of 3 inputs. On wider screens, the 2 groups should be side-by-side, and on narrower screens, the two groups should be stacked. The 3 input items inside the groups should always be side-by-side.

In all cases, the input items should be evenly sized across the width of the window. In other words, on larger screens, I should see 6 inputs equally sized side-by-side, taking up the width of the window. On smaller screens, I should see 3 inputs equally sized taking up the width of the window, stacked on top of 3 similar inputs.

As I grow or shrink the window, the inputs should change size proportionally. When the window is too small for the 6 inputs to fit side-by-side, it should then go to the 2 groups of 3, with the 3 inputs in each group expanding so that the group takes up the width of the window.

I want to do this specifically with flexbox. I realize media queries can do this, but I will eventually be embedding this in a growable div, so media queries will not work.

This code sample comes close, in that it does the wrapping, but it will not grow the inputs (or the div wrappers around the inputs for that matter) to take up the width of the window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flex Test</title>
    <style>
        .row {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .group {
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            flex: 1 0 100%;
        }
        .item {
            flex: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="display:flex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="group">
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test2">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test2">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your desired layout is possible without media queries. Since you want your inputs to be flexible and occupy the full width of the container, they need some way to know when to wrap. Media queries and fixed widths are good triggers.

In this answer I'll highlight some problems with your code, which may help you get a better grasp of the situation.

This is your original CSS, with my comments:

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex; /* valid */
}

.row {
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* INVALID #1 */
    flex-grow: 1; /* valid */
}

.group {
    display: inline-flex; /* valid */
    flex-wrap: nowrap; /* valid */
    flex: 1 0 100%; /* INVALID #2 */
}

.item {
    flex: 1; /* valid */
}
```

INVALID #1:

This code is invalid because the [**`flex-wrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) property applies only to flex containers. As you haven't applied `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to `.row`, this element is not a flex container and `flex-wrap` is simply ignored.

INVALID #2:

This code is invalid because the [**`flex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property applies only to flex items. As the parent element – `.row` – is not a flex container, then `.group` is not a flex item and the `flex` property is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The media query can be easily translated into flex.

the trick is that you need to change a little bit the approach

Let's say that you want the media query break point to be at 500px. Higher than that, and we will have the inline approach

That translates in the flex-basis of the inner elements being half that value, 250px. It will allow the posibility to set the 2 elements in the same row when the container is above 500px (so that the 2 fit).

I have added borders in the elements so that it's easy to see what is what.

```css
div {
  margin: 3px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  border: 2px solid  red;
}


.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  flex: 100% 1 1;
}

.group {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 250px 1 1;
}

.item {
  flex: auto 1 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="group">
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test2">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test2">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input text="test3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help from you two. It helped lead to the answer I wanted. The answer I think depends on making the middle group both a flex container and a flex item, as follows:

```
<style>
    .row {
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .group {
        margin:10px;
        flex: 1 300px;
        background:lightblue;
        display:inline-flex;
    }
    .item {
        padding:10px;
        flex:1 100%;
        background: lavender;
    }
    .inwrap input {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="group">
        <div class = "item">
            <div class = "inwrap"><input text="test"></div>

        </div>
        <div class = "item">
            <div class = "inwrap"><input text="test"></div>

        </div>
        <div class = "item">
            <div class = "inwrap"><input text="test"></div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class = "item">
            <div class = "inwrap"><input text="test"></div>

        </div>
        <div class = "item">
            <div class = "inwrap"><input text="test"></div>

        </div>
        <div class = "item">
            <div class = "inwrap"><input text="test"></div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```